# I am trying to get my image to display from this for loop from the array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, for-loop

I am trying to get the links in the array objects to display when the loop goes through but they appear as broken links. [broken link code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1hC8.png)

```
<p id= "tracks"> </p>
<div id = "images"> </div>
<script>

let songs = [
  {
    title: "Getting Away with It (All Messed Up)",
    artist: "James",
    album: "Pleased to Meet You",
    year: 2001,
    art: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2a/JamesPleasedToMeetYou.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "Renaissance Affair",
    artist: "Hooverphonic",
    album: "Blue Wonder Power Milk",
    year: 1998,
    art: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/17/Hooverphonic-Blue_Wonder_Power_Milk.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "White Nights",
    artist: "Oh Land",
    album: "Oh Land",
    year: 2011,
    art: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/68/Oh_Land_%28album%29.png"
  }
]
  // Javascript Code here
 element_p = document.getElementById("tracks")
 //alert (element_p.innerHTML); 
 let text = "";

 for (let data of songs) {
  let new_paragraph= document.createElement ('p');
 new_paragraph.innerHTML = 'Title: '+ data.title + " <br> Album: "+ data.album+ ' <br> Artist: ' + data.artist + "<br> Year: "+ data.year
  element_p.appendChild(new_paragraph)
 }
element_div = document.getElementById ("images")
let image = "";

for (let photo of songs){
 let img_node = document.createElement ('IMG');
 img_node.setAttribute('src', "data.art");
 document.getElementById("images").appendChild (img_node);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried two different ways and this way is the only way at least the broken links show up. Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Pleas include your code in the question

Comment: sorry about that just added it

Comment: @JenniferGarcia in this img_node.setAttribute('src', "data.art"); data.art shouldn't be in quotes I guess ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `img_node.setAttribute('src', photo.art)`. like below example:

```
...
for (let photo of songs){
  let img_node = document.createElement ('img');
  img_node.setAttribute('src', photo.art);
  document.getElementById("images").appendChild(img_node);
}
```

Comment: Why did you accept this answer? The code is broken. It declares `let photo` but then accesses `data.art`.

Comment: Also using `IMG` is acceptable. Case doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'data.art' you have to pass in the url from each photo you are passing in by using photo.art

Answer (score -1):

You have `data.art` in quotes so its treated as a string instead of an object. Also, your for loop is declaring `photo` so you should change `data.art` to `photo.art`. Like this:

```
for (let photo of songs){
  let img_node = document.createElement ('IMG');
  img_node.setAttribute('src', photo.art);
  document.getElementById("images").appendChild (img_node);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, but you accepted the broken answer :(

Comment: let appears to be an array of js objects so src "value" should be let[index].art

Comment: Also "data.art" should not have quotes unless you use eval("data.art") which sould be let[index].art eval("let[index].art")

Comment: Samuel, you are commenting on the wrong answer. Also, `songs` is an array, `let photo` represents each object in the array. So you'd access the art by using `photo.art`. Nothing is in quotes.